# R library(FSelector) failed to run due to java error

Tags: r, rjava, mlr, fselector

I have been trying to get FSelector from MLR package working recently, but have been running into the same java issue on my mac:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘FSelector’:
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
>     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libjvm.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
>       /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libclient.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Does anyone know how to fix the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling rJava? This has nothing to do with FSelector or mlr.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yeah ive done it couple times followed bunch other thread , but the problem doesnt go away. Im abke to load mlr just not fselector or rjava

Comment: Have you tried installing another JDK?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes I did, doesn’t help either. I have a Mac too

Comment: From the error message it looks like you installed the wrong JDK for your system.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff is it because of the location ?

Comment: "mach-o, but wrong architecture"

Comment: @LarsKotthoff what does architecture mean in this case ?

Comment: The machine architecture of your laptop. Just make sure that you download and install the right JDK.